# How to call a method in another method in Java (same class)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to call a method from another method in the same class to check if something entered by the user is in an arrayList. If it is in the arrayList, I want to add 1 to its quantity. If it's not in the arrayList, I'll add it to the arrayList. Here's what I have:

```
public Item searchForItem(String n){
  for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){   
    Item y = s.get(i);  
    if(y.getName().equals(name)){  
      return y;    
    } 
  }
  return null;
}
public void addItem(Item f) {  
  s.add(f);    
}
```

I know that I'll need an if statement in the `addItem` method, but I'm not sure how to write it.

Is there a way to check if either `y` was returned or whether `null` was returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the searchForItem method passing name as an argument.

```
public void addItem(Item f) {  
 if(searchForItem(f.getName())==null) {
  s.add(f);    // add's the item only if searchForItem returns null
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach syntax for simpler code, and try something like this:

```
public Item searchForItem(String name){
  for(Item y : s) {   
    if(y.getName().equals(name)){  
      return y;    
    } 
  }
  s.add(new Item(name));
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap! It will have O(1) access time so that you don't have to iterate the array list. Use the containsKey method to check if the element is in the map, and the get method to obtain it.